# android: no class def found error from library project

Tags: android, android-library

i am getting a noclassdeffound exception, when running my app with the emulator:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityPano.this, ActivityTable.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

the ActivityTable is causing the exception.

it is defined in an android-library project, which i have included in the java build path as well as in the android references dialog. there are no errors in eclipse, but when started in the emulator it crashes.

here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mypackage"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:debuggable="false" android:description="@string/description">
        <activity android:name=".ActivityHPanorama"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.mypackage.ActivityTable"></activity>

    </application>


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"></uses-sdk>
</manifest>
```

this is the error from the logcat:

```
04-18 11:32:07.767: ERROR/dalvikvm(483): Could not find class com.mypackage.ActivityTable', referenced from method com.mypackage.ActivityHPanorama.onCreate
```

what makes me a bit suspicious is this line from the console (not the logcat):

```
[2011-04-18 14:55:59 - panorama] Could not find panorama.apk!
```

panorama is the name of the library project.

Comment: can you paste the contents of your manifest file here?

Comment: The problem is that you haven't defined any intent-filters for your "ActivityTable" as well... Look for my answer below..

Answer (score 1):

If you are depenedencies are correct when you are installing the app you should see following in console logs

> [2011-04-19 16:41:10 - TicTacToe] Installing TicTacToe.apk...
>
> [2011-04-19 16:41:12 - TicTacToe] Success!

But since you were mentioning that Could not find panorama.apk! I tried replicating such behaviour using tic-tac-toe sameple library..

This is what i did,

Added TicTacToe Library to eclipse, Added TicTacToe app also to eclipse.

Right clicked on Library project, went to android tab and removed the IsLibrary check

Right clicked on Main app project, went to android tab removed dependency

The went to java build path of Main app project and added Library project as required project

Compilation went fine, but when installing the app it is checking for library.apk I am guessing if you are doing anything similar tat might be the issue.

> [2011-04-19 16:42:16 - TicTacToe] Installing TicTacToe.apk...
>
> [2011-04-19 16:42:20 - TicTacToe] Success! [2011-04-19 16:42:20 -
> TicTacToe] Project dependency found, installing: TicTacToeLib
>
> [2011-04-19 16:42:20 - TicTacToeLib] Uploading TicTacToeLib.apk onto
> device 'SH0A5PL08769' [2011-04-19 16:42:20 - TicTacToeLib] Installing
> TicTacToeLib.apk... [2011-04-19 16:42:24 - TicTacToeLib] Success!

Comment: please post your logcat logs, most likely it will be a warning message. Also can you post your default.properties here

Comment: try copying all the declarations of activities , providers, receivers services etc.. in your android manifest.xml

Comment: i can't see how this makes any sense. the error is beause the VM cant find the class file of this one class.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, but infact the library flag is checked on the library project.

Answer (score -1):

have you add this class in your Manifest?

`<activity android:name="ActivityTable"></activity>`

Comment: I thik you should take off the package name because it's already specified in the root tag , so you should put it like this : 

 `<activity android:name=".ActivityTable"></activity>`

and don't forget the dot in the beggining

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use

```
 Intent myScreen = new Intent();
    myScreen.setClassName(YourCurrentScreen.this,
fullpackagename.yourclassName.class.getName());
    startActivityForResult(myScreen, 0);
```

This would definitely work

Comment: nope, i am still getting the same error. what exactly do you mean with YourCurrentScreen ?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you haven't defined any intent-filters for your "ActivityTable" as well...

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityTable" 
                  android:label="ActivityTable">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This should help..

Comment: thanks, but it still gives the same error, if i add this intent-filter

Comment: 04-18 11:32:07.767: ERROR/dalvikvm(483): Could not find class 'com.mypackage.ActivityTable', referenced from method com.mypackage.ActivityHPanorama.onCreate

Comment: you can see the detailed error message in the Logcat. Just copy the error message from it and paste it here.. this would help to find the exact cause..